# Why doesn't System.Timers.Timer update non-busy UI?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, timer

I have been looking for a reason, but about every single topic on stackoverflow I could find suggested a busy UI as the reason.
I have very basic code, just for testings and it simply won't update the UI, even though I am sure it cannot be busy doing something else:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static double t = 0;
    static double dt = 0.1;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(5000);
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Update);
        timer.Start();
    }

    void Update(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        t = t + dt;
        testBlock1.Text = (t).ToString();
    }
}
```

I debugged it and set a breakpoint to the `textBlock1.Text` update and it did break every 5 seconds, but the UI is never updated. As can be seen in the code, **when I move my mouse over the `Button` I use to start the timer, the button shows its typical "mouse-over-button" animation.** Why does that happen, but not the text update?

If anyone can lead me to a good topic on stackoverflow, please do so and I will delete my question here, but I couldn't find any topic explaining why this approach doesn't update the UI even though the UI is not busy doing anyting else.

Comment: @Ian It will, but the line `(t + dt).ToString();` makes little sense right after `t = t + dt;`...

Comment: The initial text of the textbox is "TextBox" and the t is update on every Update using `t = t+dt` as can be seen in my question.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth that was a small mistake, I corrected it, thanks.

Comment: The `Timer` is its own thread.  The question's answer you read were incorrect, the problem is, your trying to update the `UI Thread` in a seperate thread.  The solution is to use a `Dispatcher` in the case of a WPF Window and/or `Invoke` in the case of Win32 forms.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "the question's answer" but both answers on this page explain that is a cross thread problem, so both answers actually apply to my question directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For WPF, you should use `DispatcherTimer` -
Also with the above code you posted, i am getting a `cross thread` error since `elapsed` event is raised on other thread and not on `UI thread`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
   timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
   timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
   timer.Start();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   t = t + dt;
   txt.Text = (t + dt).ToString();
}
```

**EDIT**

Also, you can marshal it on UI Dispatcher with your existing code like this -

```
void Update(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate()
    {
        t = t + dt;
        txt.Text = (t + dt).ToString();
    });
}
```

Comment: You might consider removing this answer and just upvoting the answer provided by @Jon because he stated in the last sentence that the OP should just use a `DispatchTimer`.

Comment: I think I would like to keep this answer as it also provides simple code exactly for my problem. In general thank you for the answer, it works.

Comment: I updated my accepted answer to yours, because of the code provided that is directly applicable to my problem, thanks again.

Answer (score 12):

[`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) won't *by default* marshal back to the UI thread.  In Windows Forms you can make it do so easily enough:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(5000);
timer.SynchronizingObject = this;
```

... but WPF UI elements don't implement `ISynchronizeInvoke`, which would stop this from working for you in WPF.

You could use the `Dispatcher` to marshal over to the UI thread within the handler, or you could just use a [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) to start with.

Comment: But interestingly, this would have resulted in a cross-thread UI access error, and the OP didn't state that. Or is this only the case in WinForms?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Doesn't that depend on the build configuration? I think it does under WinForms - not sure about WPF.

Comment: But the timer raises an event in the UI thread, shouldn't that update the UI independent of the fact that the timer runs in a different thread?

Comment: @phil13131: that is in fact the issue Jon is trying to point out. The `Timer` you're using doesn't implicitly change threads and thus the method handler is raised on a different thread.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Interesting then that no access error occours then, as I try to update UI components...

Comment: @phil13131, I have personally experienced this in WPF as well - in that while the statements don't throw an exception, the UI simply doesn't update.

Comment: @BigM It is interesting that C# throws exceptions quite fast when it comes to cross-thread access problems, but in this context it simply ignores it. C# feature or bug?!

Comment: @phil13131 - I guarantee you its not a bug. Its not a feature. The fact your `UI Thread` is deadlocked with the `Timer` lock is a bug in your original code ( hence the inability for the UI to be updated ).

Comment: The question is rather, why there is no cross thread exception, as I still try to access some UI text from my timer thread, but no exception is thrown, so this code is simply ignored. Why? I understand now it is wrong to update the UI from the Timer thread, but that still doesn't clearify the missing exception.

Comment: @Ramhound: I see no sign that there's a deadlock here. Why do you think there is?

Comment: @phil13131: It's not up to C# at all. C# is just the language. It's up to the UI framework. I don't know what WPF's policy is on this - or indeed what configuration you're building, or whether you're running in the debugger, both of which could affect this.